# ntdll!kifastsystemcallret

Tags: c++, windows, crash

My program is crashing at the end of execution, and couldnt even see stack unwind info.
all i can see is this " ntdll!kifastsystemcallret", can some throw some light?

Comment: "couldnt even see stack unwind info", this means...i've been trying with windbg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KiFastSystemCallRet means that the thread is in a syscall - an unfortunate aspect of x86 NT syscall dispatch is that it will not return the context back to the original place, but has to return to a static location in ntdll, which will fix up the context and put you back where you came from. Paste in the stacks and we can give you some more hints...

Answer (score 3):

You'll quite often see this on all the threads that are just waiting -- one of the threads should hopefully have some more useful stack, the rest are likely to show this.  Try installing the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx) and run the program in `windbg`.  When the crash occurs type `!analyze -v` to get a useful post-mortem of the likely cause of the crash.

Comment: What does the 'analyze' command do? My Project Manager is saying that windbg is a "lightweight version of Visual Studio" (we use VS2008), but the fact that people are recommending it here suggests that it has functionality that VS doesn't have.

Can I do the equivalent of 'analyze' in VS2008? If so, can someone tell me how?

Comment: Firstly, apologies - it should have been '!analyze -v'.  Secondly, I'd suggest upgrading your Project Manager :-)  Windbg isn't a 'lightweight' version of Visual Studio, it's a low level debugger. You can't write code in it or compile anything.  It gives you a lot more access to low level data about processes, handles, locks, etc, and has some extra functions such as '!analyze' which applies a number of heuristics to figure out the most likely place where a crash occurred, and often *how* it occurred.  Windbg doesn't cost anything and it doesn't replace VS - you can use both together.

Answer (score 0):

You can try debugging by attaching [windbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) and provide reference to OS symbols. Might give some clue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a call stack with more information, like what operation is being done before this particular crash occurs. i have faced such crashed before.

It could very well be a first chance exception also. Are you sure it is a crash?

Answer (score -2):

kifastsystemcallret ~ Kernel Fast System Call Return, or emergency exit from a Kernel function ? some kernel invocation failed ...